# How can I fix my postcss config so that the ":has" plugin works?

Tags: javascript, css, postcss

I am using postcss with vue 3 (vite). Here is my config:

package.json

```
    "postcss-preset-env": "^7.8.3",
```

postcss.config.js

```
const postcssPresetEnv = require("postcss-preset-env");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    postcssPresetEnv({
      features: {
        "nesting-rules": true,
        "has-pseudo-class": true,
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

Nesting is working as expected, so I guess my config is correct

`has-pseudo-class` is doing nothing on Firefox 107

I know that this isn't working because the following code produces a purple border on Chromium (which natively supports `:has`), but nothing on Firefox 107:

```
.draggable:has(div) {
  border: 1px solid purple !important;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Have I misunderstood what the plugin does or how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was not working because I needed to import and bootstrap the browser polyfill.

To solve the issue I added the following code to my HTML head

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/css-has-pseudo@4.0.1/dist/browser-global.js"></script>
<script>cssHasPseudo(document, { hover: true })</script>
```

Note that you need to match the browser polyfill to the version of `postcss-preset-env` that you are using.

Thanks a bunch to the very helpful folks on the [postcss discord chan](https://discord.gg/bUadyRwkJS) for helping me troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't support the :has pseudo-class, so it won't polyfill it.

The Mozilla CSS Docs State
"From version 103: this feature is behind thelayout.css.has-selector.enabled preferences (needs to be set to true). To change preferences in Firefox, visit about:config."

See browser specifications [here](https://I%20am%20using%20postcss%20with%20vue%203%20(vite).%20Here%20is%20my%20config:%20%20package.json%20%20%20%20%20%20%22postcss-preset-env%22:%20%22%5E7.8.3%22,%20postcss.config.js%20%20const%20postcssPresetEnv%20=%20require(%22postcss-preset-env%22);%20%20module.exports%20=%20%7B%20%20%20plugins:%20%5B%20%20%20%20%20postcssPresetEnv(%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20features:%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22nesting-rules%22:%20true,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22has-pseudo-class%22:%20true,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%7D),%20%20%20%5D,%20%7D;%20Nesting%20is%20working%20as%20expected,%20so%20I%20guess%20my%20config%20is%20correct%20%20has-pseudo-class%20is%20doing%20nothing%20on%20Firefox%20107%20%20I%20know%20that%20this%20isn%27t%20working%20because%20the%20following%20code%20produces%20a%20purple%20border%20on%20Chromium%20(which%20natively%20supports%20:has),%20but%20nothing%20on%20Firefox%20107:%20%20.draggable:has(div)%20%7B%20%20%20border:%201px%20solid%20purple%20!important;%20%7D%20What%20am%20I%20doing%20wrong?%20Have%20I%20misunderstood%20what%20the%20plugin%20does%20or%20how%20to%20use%20it?)